# Why 1 and 1.0 have different prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why extending `Number` prototype works for `1.2` but not for `1`?

```js
Number.prototype.to_s = function () {
  return "" + this
}

console.log(1.2.to_s())
console.log(1.to_s())
```

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: `console.log((1).to_s())`, it's a basic syntax issue, the `.` is taken to be a decimal point and part of a numeric constant.

Comment: Extending the prototype works for both `1` and `1.2` and both are of the type `Number`. But whenever you see a `SyntaxError` then the syntax of your code is not correct and this means that your code does not run at all.

Answer (score 1):

When there is a `.` in the end it is a part of the number.

You can use double dots to get past your issue for `1.`

```js
Number.prototype.to_s = function () {
  return "" + this
}

let y = 1.2; // no issues;
let x = 1.; //no issues
console.log(x,y);

console.log(1..to_s());
console.log(1.2.to_s());
```

Also, there is a slight color difference in the two dots in the code snippet itself. So code editors also are pointing you towards the right syntax.